# How to make postfix (--) in Text.Parsec.Expr

Tags: haskell, parsec

I've got an example from documentation for [`Text.Parsec.Expr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Expr.html).

```
expr    = buildExpressionParser table term
          <?> "expression"
term    =  parens expr 
      <|> natural
      <?> "simple expression"
table   = [ [prefix "-" negate, prefix "+" id ]
          , [postfix "++" (+1)]  
          , [binary "*" (*) AssocLeft, binary "/" (div) AssocLeft ]
          , [binary "+" (+) AssocLeft, binary "-" (-)   AssocLeft ]
          ]
```

I'd tried to add postfix `--` operation and changed the second line for table to

```
          , [postfix "++" (+1), postfix "--" (subtract 1)]
```

Now

```
runParser expr () "expr" "1--"
```

give me `Right 1` in ghci.

Why I got it and how to provide postfix (`--`)?

Comment: I used `natural = P.natural lexer` and `lexer = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef`. In Daniel Fischer's answer `natural = fmap read $ many1 digit` and it works well. What is the difference? Why it doesn't work with lexer?

Comment: Daniel gave a complete answer. Problem with (--) as line comment in Haskell...

Comment: Parsing problems aside, the conventional behavior of a postfix `++` or `--` operator is that it can be applied only to an lvalue, yielding the unmutated lvalue, with a side-effect.  In that context, `1--` doesn't make sense because `1` is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"--1"` gets parsed as `[prefix "-", prefix "-", number 1]` and evaluated as `negate (negate 1)` which yields 1.

<del>To get a postfix `(--)`, does `runParser expr () "expr" "1--"` not give you a postfix `--`?</del>

<del>The parse seems to not consume the entire input. I can't tell why, though,</del>

```
module ExParse where

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Expr

parens p = do
    char '('
    e <- p
    char ')'
    return e

reservedOp s = do
    string s
    notFollowedBy letter

natural = fmap read $ many1 digit

expr    = buildExpressionParser table term
          <?> "expression"
term    =  parens expr 
      <|> natural
      <?> "simple expression"
table   = [ [prefix "-" negate, prefix "+" id ]
          , [postfix "++" (+1), postfix "--" (subtract 1)]  
          , [binary "*" (*) AssocLeft, binary "/" (div) AssocLeft ]
          , [binary "+" (+) AssocLeft, binary "-" (-)   AssocLeft ]
          ]

binary  name fun assoc = Infix (do{ reservedOp name; return fun }) assoc
prefix  name fun       = Prefix (do{ reservedOp name; return fun })
postfix name fun       = Postfix (do{ reservedOp name; return fun })

res = runParser expr () "expr" "1--"
```

yields

```
*ExParse> res
Right 0
```

as desired here.

The problem with `natural = P.natural lexer` is that it is defined as

```
natural = lexeme nat
```

and

```
lexeme p = do
    x <- p
    whiteSpace
    return x
```

where comments count as whitespace. Now, the line comments in Haskell start with `--`, hence with `natural = P.natural lexer`, the `natural` consumes the entire string `"1--"`. To make `--` usable as a postfix operator, you have to choose a language definition where that is not a comment starter. For example, you can modify `haskellDef` per

```
lexer = P.makeTokenParser (haskellDef{P.commentLine = "//"})
```

or redefine the `whiteSpace` parser.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant 1-- really

Comment: Great! The difference with my code is following. I had natural = P.natural lexer and lexer = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef. And import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P